# Dynamically allow/deny properties in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using a `View Model` with properties for passing the data as `JSON` to java script.

```
public string Property1 { get; set; }  //deny for user1
public string Property2{ get; set; }   //denyfor user2
public string Property3{ get; set; }
```

Now I have different types of users so depending upon the user I want denyor allow properties to be mapped and displayed on the UI

Comment: Json.NET allows conditional property serialization, although it may not fit your scenario. You could clone the original object, copying only the permitted properties, and then serialize the result. How are permissions determined?

Comment: yes I found JsonIgnore Attribute I guess I have customize it according to my requirement and for permissions I have a permission service which when provided with user and module gives it is required or not

Comment: It will be helpful if i can get a way to customize the JsonIgnore attribute

Comment: I had in mind the `ShouldSerialize{MethodName}` [methods](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ConditionalProperties.htm). You can define a complex rule but you can't pass arguments and the method has to be defined on the DTO itself.

Comment: You *can* go deep in customizing what gets serialized, using a custom [ContractResolver](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/html/ContractResolver.htm) class. A ContractResolver can reproduce what the attributes or the methods do, but it does require a bit more coding

Comment: thanks for the suggestion I will check it out post a solution which worked for me

Comment: Have you set Role for each user?

Answer (score 0):

How about a custom getter that checks the authorization rules, and returns null if authorization fails?  Then you can set up your serializer to not serialize nulls.

```
JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };

private string _property1;
public string Property1 
{ 
    get 
    {
        if(getcurrentuser.isauthorizedforproperty1)
        {
            return _property1;
        }
        else 
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        _property1 = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, you are correct.  It does indeed.  I'll leave this here just in case someone stumbles across this page using a different serializer without that functionality, like the MS JavaScriptSerializer.